# How can I get the probability of winning in this stopping game until nth event happens?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose that events occur according a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Each time an event occurs we must decide whether or not to stop, with our objective being to stop at the last event to occur prior to some specified time $\tau$. That is, if an event occurs at time t, 0 $\le$ t < $\tau$, and we decide to stop,then we lose if there are any events in the interval ( t, $\tau$ ), and win otherwise. If we have not stopped before time $\tau$ we also loose. Consider the strategy that we wait until the nth event happens and then stop inmediatly. Find the probability of winning. What is the n that maximize the probability of winning?

I have that P{winning}=(N($\tau$)-N(n)=0); since there must not be events in the interval (k,T]
P{winning}=$\frac{(\lambda(T-n))^0}{0!}e^{-\lambda(T-n)}=e^{-\lambda(T-n)}$

Now, to get $n_{max}$: $\frac{d(P\{winning\})}{dn}= \frac{d(e^{-\lambda(T-n)})}{dn}=\lambda e^{-\lambda(T-n)}=0\rightarrow e^{-\lambda(T-n)}=0\rightarrow n=-\infty$

I am not sure if I proceeding correctly and in that case I don´t know how to interpret that value for n

Comment: In your first expression, the exponent should be $-\lambda(T-t(n))$.  You need the units to match, so need the time of the $n^{th}$ event, not the number $n$.  I think your optimal strategy is not to wait for $n$ events, but to wait a time $t'$, then stop after the next event.

Answer (score 3):

Your Poisson process has a rate of $\lambda$ (per unit time I presume).  In the game, the process runs for a length of time $\tau$.  So the number of events in time $\tau$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\tau\lambda$.

Your strategy amount to making a guess $n$ of the number of occurrences in the given $\tau$ time interval.

So the probability that you win is $e^{-\tau\lambda}\frac{(\tau\lambda)^n}{n!}$.  The $n$ that maximizes this probability is $n=\lfloor \tau\lambda \rfloor$ (for this, see for instance [The mode of the Poisson Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246496/the-mode-of-the-poisson-distribution)).

Answer (score 0):

P(win)=P(N(T)=k)=$\frac{(\lambda \tau)^n}{n!} exp\{-\lambda \tau\}$ Since by time $\tau$, there must be k events becuase if there are more than k, we will loose. But I still can get the n that maximizes the probability of winning