# Probability of winning based on stop time

Tags: probability

[image]

I understand the process of solving this problem but there is one thing that I am confused about.

Why, in order to win, do we need $N(\tau)-N(s)=1$?
I thought that the number of events in $(s, \tau]$ is given by $N(\tau)-N(s)$ so it would make sense that we want this to to be $0$, in order to win.

[How can I get the probability of winning in this stopping game until nth event happens?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153952/how-can-i-get-the-probability-of-winning-in-this-stopping-game-until-nth-event-h)
Link to question asked before but this specific problem I am having was not addressed.

Comment: Well, if an event happens at exactly time $\tau$, then you want $N(\tau)-N(s)=1.$

Comment: @mjw The way I read it we do not want any events in $(s, \tau]$ ?

Comment: $(s,\tau)$ or $(s,\tau]$?

Comment: @mjw Please see the update, it is directly from the textbook.

Comment: Okay, got it, thank you!  I guess that in the light of the update, these comments are unnecessary.  Glad you got a clearer picture and an answer that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are zero events in the interval $(s,\tau)$, then you lose because you never stop.

If there are two or more events in $(s,\tau)$, then you lose because you stop on the first one, and then a second one occurs before $\tau$, so you did not stop on the last event before $\tau$.

Only when there is exactly one event in $(s,t)$ do you win, because then that event you stop on is the last event to occur.

Comment: Whoops, there is my problem, I assumed $s$ was the time that you stop, when actually you stop on the first event after $s$