# Why does the pmf for a Poisson Distribution Maximize at $x = \lambda$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, poisson-distribution

For a random variable $X$ s.t. $X$ has a Poisson distribution:

$$
P(k \text{ events in interval}) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}
$$

The following graph seems to indicate that the maximum probability value is $k = \lambda$ (and perhaps also $\lambda-1$).

[image: Poisson Distribution]

**Question:** Formally, why is this the case?

I have been able to do some algebraic manipulation:

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} = \frac{\lambda^x}{x! \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}}
$$

so that

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{\lambda^x}{\lambda^x + x! \left( \sum_{n=0}^{x-1} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} + \sum_{m=x+1}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^m}{m!} \right)}
$$

But it is still not clear to me why the maximum is at $x = \lambda$ and $x = \lambda-1$.

Comment: Are you assuming $\lambda$ is an integer?

Comment: For purposes of this discussion, we can assume that yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The mode of the Poisson Distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246496/the-mode-of-the-poisson-distribution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $k\ge 0$, we calculate the **ratio**
$$\frac{\Pr(X=k+1)}{\Pr(X=k)}.\tag{1}$$
This is
$$\frac{e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}},$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{\lambda}{k+1}.$$
Thus if $\lambda \lt 1$, then the ratio (1) is $\lt 1$ at $k=0$, and even smaller afterwards. Thus $\Pr(X=k)$ is steadily decreasing, and therefore our probability attains a maximum at $k=0$.

If $\lambda$ is a positive integer, then the ratio (1) is greater than $1$ if $k+1\lt \lambda$, is equal to $1$ if $k+1=\lambda$, and is less than $1$ if $k+1\gt \lambda$. Thus our probability attains a maximum at $k=\lambda-1$ and also at $k=\lambda$.

Finally, suppose $\lambda\gt 1$ and $\lambda$ is not an integer. Then the ratio (1) is greater than $1$ if $k-1\lt \lambda$, and is less than $1$ if $k\gt \lambda$, so our probability attains a maximum at $k=\lfloor \lambda\rfloor$.