# Maximising $\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, factorial, maxima-minima

Let $x$ be a number such that $x\gt 0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that the maximum value of the expression
$$\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
occurs for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $n=\lceil x \rceil - 1$? If true, how does one prove this?

My attempt was to find conditions such that
$$\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \gt \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
$$\frac{x}{n+1} \gt 1$$
$$x\gt n+1$$
So the consecutive values of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ are only increasing if $x\gt n+1$ which will be true for all $n+1\lt x$ - the maximum of which is $n+1=\lfloor x \rfloor$. This leads to the value given above.

Comment: What you want is related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246496/the-mode-of-the-poisson-distribution/246507#246507. (There, they are maximising $\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ as a function of $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Their $\lambda$ is your $x$.)

Comment: Your way is very good for it. Good job

Answer (score 4):

To find the maximum value in the sequence $\left(\tfrac{x^n}{n!}\right)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$, note that for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ the ratio of two consecutive terms is
$$\frac{\tfrac{x^n}{n!}}{\tfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}=\frac{n+1}{x},$$
so the sequence is increasing as long as $n<x-1$ and decreasing when $n>x-1$. This means the sequence is maximal at $n=\lceil x-1\rceil=\lceil x\rceil-1$. If $x$ is an integer then it is also maximal at $n=\lceil x\rceil$.

Comment: Inequalities are wrong here, it should be like in the question

Comment: @Jakobian You are right, I have corrected them.