# Poisson distribution/ finding special k

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ be  a discrete random variable with its probability mass function:

$$p_X(k)= P(X=k) \ for\ k\in \mathbb{N}_0 $$.

I want to find $k_0$,such that $p_X(k_0) \geq p_X(k) \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0 $
I consider the Poisson distribution.

My idea ist to consider $ \frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{k}}{k!}} = \frac{\lambda}{k+1}>1 \Leftrightarrow \lambda >k+1 \Leftrightarrow \lambda-1 >k$

So $ k_0 = \lambda-1 \ \ for  \lambda \in \mathbb{N} $

Is this the right track?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246496/the-mode-of-the-poisson-distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:)