# Why does $P(X=E(X)) = P(X=E(X)-1)$ in the Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

When a discrete random variable follows the Poisson distribution and if $E(X)$ is a natural number, $E(X)$ has the greatest probability, but why does $E(X)-1$ have the same probability?

Comment: Are you asking for the calculation (i.e. $\frac{n^n}{n!}=\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$) or some high-level (e.g. perhaps combinatorial) explanation?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246507/15941) for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fleshing out the first part of Brian Moehring's comment: If $X$ is Poisson with mean $E[X]=\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an integer, then $P(X=\lambda) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^\lambda}{\lambda!}$ while $P(X=\lambda-1) = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{\lambda - 1}}{(\lambda-1)!}$.

Comment: So is   \frac{\lambda^\lambda}{\lambda!}  equal to  \frac{\lambda^{\lambda - 1}}{(\lambda-1)!}

Comment: @shreck357 Well yes, that is the crux of the problem. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I sadly do not know how to manipulate factorials

Comment: @shreck357 Try to show that $\lambda! = \lambda \cdot (\lambda-1)!$.

Comment: Just to clarify multiply RHS by lambda/lambda

Answer (score 0):

A comment has made clear the problem is not understanding factorials well. Note that$$(k+1)!=\underbrace{1\cdot2\cdot\dots\cdot k}_{k!}\cdot(k+1)=k!(k+1),$$so$$\frac{P(X=k+1)}{P(X=k)}=\frac{\frac{\lambda^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}e^{-\lambda}}{\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}=\lambda\frac{k!}{(k+1)!}=\frac{\lambda}{k+1}.$$At first, the ratio of consecutive probabilities is high, but it quickly diminishes. (That makes sense: the probabilities haev to shrink eventually for infinitely many of them to sum to $1$, but we expect very small $k$ to be improbable if $\lambda$ is very large, so probabilities have to rise at first.) In particular:

- $P(X=k+1)>P(X=k)$ if $k<\lambda-1$;
- $P(X=k+1)=P(X=k)$ if $k=\lambda-1$; and
- $P(X=k+1)<P(X=k)$ if $k>\lambda-1$.