# Poisson distribution with an integer $\lambda$ value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, intuition, poisson-distribution

I have noticed that when a Poisson distribution has an integer value of $\lambda$, the following holds:
$$
\mathbb{P}[X = \lambda] = \mathbb{P}[X = \lambda - 1]
$$

I have been able to prove this rather simply using an algebraic method. However, my question is, ***is there an intuitive reason for why this is the case***? For example, if an average of 10 phone calls are received an hour, why is it that 10 phone calls are equally likely as 9 phone calls?

Comment: @Clarinetist the OP already said he has an algebraic proof and was looking for the intuition behind the result... not sure this qualifies as intuition...

Comment: When $\lambda$ is an integer, modes of the distribution are $\lambda$ and $\lambda-1$.

Comment: Good question. +1

Comment: This question is answered in detail here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210475/why-two-modes-for-a-poisson-distribution-with-lambda-an-integer

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/246496/321264

Comment: The best answer I could find on this topic is given here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210475/why-two-modes-for-a-poisson-distribution-with-lambda-an-integer

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can see is to consider the Poisson distribution as a binomial limit and try to see intuitively why the recursive formula

$$\mathbb{P}[X = k] = \frac{\lambda}{k}\mathbb{P}[X = k - 1]$$

holds. Then, if $\lambda = k$, the numerator and denominator cancel out.

Say that you recieve an average of $\lambda$ phone calls in your working day. Consider your day as divided into a large number $n$ time slots, and that the probability of recieving a call in a given time slot has independent probability $\lambda/n$. Then in the limit as $n \to \infty$ the number of calls $Y_n$ per day has the Poisson($\lambda$) distribution.

Let $p_k = \mathbb{P}[Y_n = k]$. We now want to understand why

$$ p_k \approx \frac{\lambda}{k}p_{k-1}\,.$$

**Warm-up:** How to obtain $p_1$ if we know $p_0$? One of the $n$ time slots should have a call instead of being empty, and there are $n$ different ways in which this can happen. Thus, with obvious notation

$$ p_1 = n\frac{p_{\mathrm{call}}}{p_\text{empty}}p_0 = n\frac{\frac{\lambda}{n}}{1-\frac{\lambda}{n}}p_0 \approx n \frac{\lambda}{n}p_0 = \lambda p_0\,.$$

The denominator $p_\text{empty}$ is close to one and will be disregarded from now on.

**General case:** To obtain $p_k$ from $p_{k-1}$ in general, there are two things going on. First, any given configuration of $k$ calls over your $n$ time slots is a factor $\lambda/n$ less likely to happen than any given configuration of $k-1$ calls:

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{slots } a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k \text{ filled}) \approx \frac{\lambda}{n}\mathbb{P}(\text{slots } b_1, b_2, \ldots b_{k-1} \text{ filled})\,.$$

Second, there are about a factor $n/k$ more ways for $k$ slots to be filled than for $k-1$ ways to be filled:
$$\binom{n}{k} \approx \frac{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}\,.$$
(It is not hard to argue this intuitively: For each placement of $k-1$ calls there are approximately $n$ empty slots in which to place an extra call, since $n$ is large. However, a given configuration of $k$ calls can be obtained from a ($k-1$)-configuration in $k$ different ways, since each of the $k$ calls could've been the last one added.)

Of course,

$$p_k = \binom{n}{k}\mathbb{P}(\text{slots } a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k \text{ filled}) \quad\text{and}\quad p_{k-1}= \binom{n}{k-1}\mathbb{P}(\text{slots } b_1, b_2, \ldots b_{k-1} \text{ filled})\,.$$
Putting these things together we obtain

$$p_k \approx \frac{n}{k}\frac{\lambda}{n}p_{k-1} = \frac{\lambda}{k}p_{k-1}\,,$$
which is what we wanted.

**Intuitive example:** It now seems to me that one can get a pretty good intuition of why $p_\lambda = p_{\lambda-1}$ holds by toying with examples and using the ideas above.

Take the example given (slightly changed): If an average of 8 phone calls are received an hour, why is it that 8 phone calls are equally likely as 7 phone calls? Divide the hour into 100 slots. The probability for some 8th time slot to turn into a phone call is 8/100. And there are approximately a factor of 100/8 more ways to recieve 8 phone calls than 7. The factors cancel. As you make the time slots smaller, the approximation becomes more exact.