# Why is the maximum of the poission distribution approx. 0.5 away from the mean?

Tags: calculus, probability

I've observed that the maximum for $(\frac{e^\lambda \lambda^x}{x!})$  And as of now, I believe that the difference $\lambda -0.5$ is convergent for $\lambda\in\mathbf N $. I ran this code and it seemed to converge for different values of mean. (m is mean ($\lambda$) in the code below). is approximately at $\lambda -0.5$. Apart from a numerical approach, is there a better way to analytically justify this behavior?

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
start = 1
end = 10
m = np.linspace(start,end,end-start+1)
val = []
for e in m:
    x = np.linspace(e - 1, e, 100)
    y = np.exp(e) * np.exp(np.log(e) * x) / sp.special.gamma(x + 1)
    y2 = np.gradient(y, x)
    xt = x[1:]
    xint = xt[y2[1:] * y2[:-1] < 0]
    val.append(e-xint-0.5)
plt.plot(m,val)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In the context of the Poisson distribution where you only care about integer $x$, the maximizer is the [mode of the distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/246507/43949), which is $\lfloor \lambda \rfloor$ if $\lambda$ is not an integer, and $\{\lambda-1, \lambda\}$ if $\lambda$ is an integer. The maximizer among real $x$ will necessarily be near there; I would guess an exact answer would require taking the derivative of the gamma function, but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really the Poisson distribution because you're treating $x$ as a continuous variable.

The logarithmic derivative of $e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x/\Gamma(x+1)$ with respect to $x$ simplifies to
$\ln(\lambda) - \Psi(x+1)$
If we take $x = \lambda - t$ with  $t$ treated as constant, then asymptotically as $\lambda \to \infty$ we have
$$ \ln(\lambda) - \Psi(\lambda-t+1) \sim \dfrac{t - 1/2}{\lambda} + O\left(\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right)$$
so this confirms your belief.

Comment: What does O(1/λ^2) mean, i tried asking my teacher and he didn't know

Comment: [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)